# Using Drag and Drop to determine identities?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

In my Android application, I have an ImageView over a separate LinearLayout as a "spawn" point. Surrounding the "spawn" are more LinearLayouts.

Let's say the ImageView is called "blue", and there are 2 other LinearLayouts. One called "blueArea" and the other "redArea". So if blue is dropped into blueArea, an action would start. If blue is dropped into redArea, another action would start.

I basically want my drops to know what is being dropped and where it is being dropped. What can I do to "tag" the ImageViews and LinearLayouts so I can detect when the view is on the layout? and how can I do this?

Here's what I have came up with so far.

```
// R.drawable.blue is the ImageView.
// R.id.blue is the LinearLayout.

public View blue = findViewById(R.drawable.blue);
findViewById(R.id.blue).setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());

findViewById(R.id.blueArea).setOnDragListener(new DragListener());
findViewById(R.id.redArea).setOnDragListener(new DragListener());
findViewById(R.id.spawn).setOnDragListener(new DragListener());

ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder;
private final class TouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        return true;
        }
    }

boolean containsDraggable = true;
class DragListener implements OnDragListener {
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
    if (action == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED) {
        }
    if (action == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED) {
        containsDraggable = true;
        }
    if (action == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED) {
        containsDraggable = false;
        }
    if (action == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION) {
        // TODO
        }
    if (action == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED) {
        if (dropEventNotHandled(event)) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    if (action == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP && containsDraggable) {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        releaseTrue();
        }
    return true;
    }
}
private boolean dropEventNotHandled(DragEvent event) {
    return !event.getResult();
    }
    public void releaseTrue() {
        score++;
        textScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }
    public void releaseFalse() {
        score--;
        textScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }
```

Comment: what if you specify a tag for every object by using setTag() method and then access the LayoutParams of the specific objects every time the move is done, then you can compare these attributes, say, on Action_Up, if they are close enough (width, height, margins), then probably they are on each other. This is not the best solution most probably, but it should work

Answer (score 2):

since you are adding

```
.setOnDragListener(new DragListener());
```

for all three views

```
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
```

will be called with above three views (ie. View v)

so you can have switch statement if you want to behave differently.

```
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.blueArea:
//action for blue..
break
}
```

Comment: This sets each case for each layout, but now I need to find out what is being dropped into it. How would I pass ClipData from my View?

Comment: View v = event.getLocalState(); will give you the (v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);) view you dragged ...